# Annoying black line in tilted LinearGradientFilling

Tags: graphics, bugs, mac-os-x, linux

**Bug introduced in 13.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.2.0 or later. This bug is OS dependent. It appears on macOS and Linux, but not Windows.**

---

This

```
Graphics[{LinearGradientFilling[{{0, Blue}, {1, LightBlue}}, -Pi/4], Rectangle[{0, 0.6}, {0.6, 1}], Filling -> Left}]
```

produces this graphic [image]

The diagonal black line is caused by the `-Pi/4` option, which makes the gradient go from the top left to the bottom right (if removed, the gradient goes from left to right and there is no black line).

I would be very grateful if someone could help me find a way (workaround/entirely different solution) of getting rid of the ugly black line. Thank you.

Edit: I'm using version "13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"

Comment: No problem on 13.0.1 on windows. screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htVUd.png)

Comment: Thanks! I should have included my version. Edited

Comment: The same bug on 13.0.1 on Linux. KUbuntu 22.04+"13.0.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (January 29, 2022)".

Comment: I think it's a bug you should report to Wolfram.

Comment: Thank you to Nasser for pointing out this is an OS-specific issue. I temporarily got around the problem by running my script in the Wolfram cloud, and reported the bug to Wolfram.